# Why EntityScan , EnableJpaRepositories annotations required if we are already using componentScan annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am already using `ComponentScan` annotation in `Main` class of `Spring Boot` app , but If I use only this annotation it will gives issue while getting repositories reference. So to overcome this I am using `EntityScan` and `EnableJpaRepositories` annotations with `componentScan`.

```
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.gonkar.fleetms.models"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.gonkar.fleetms.repositories"})
```

So my question is why its required to use other two annotations? if I am already using `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: Because entities and repository interfaces aren't component classes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `@ComponentScan` annotation is used to create beans for classes annotated with `@Component`, `@Controller` / `@RestController`, `@Service`, `@Repository`. It marks them for being added to the Spring container (making them eligible for dependency injection and allowing them to be `@Autowired`).

The `@EntityScan` annotation doesn't create any beans, it identifies which classes should be used by a JPA persistence context.

The `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation is used to create repository classes from Spring Data interfaces.

All three annotation are often used together, but they are responsible for different things.

Comment: Thanks for detailed description , But I have observed if I use only componentScan annotation it will give issue for Autowire annotation for service and repository references. Correct me if I am wrong i.e. we must use compopnentScan , EntityScan  , EnableJpaRepository  together

Comment: If some of your beans are resolved by Spring using not XML / JavaConfig but annotations, then you have yo use `@ComponentScan`. If some of your repositories are Spring Data repositories, you need to use additionaly `@EnableJpaRepositories`. And if you have some JPA entities, it's needed to use `@EntityScan`. So - yes, they must be used together.

Comment: But there are projects without persistence layer or using non-JPA persistence. In that cases there is no need to use both `@EntityScan` or `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Some works for projects using JPA but not using Spring Data - in such cases datasource, entity manager factory and transaction manager should be defined explicitly without those annotations.

Comment: Okay , Thank you very much @Alexandra Dudkina